# Third-order linear differential equation a la Sturm-Liouville

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can somebody help to find the solution of this ODE
$$
f'''+3t^2f'+3tf=\pm if,
$$
where $f=f(t)$? Without the right side, the equation is self-adjoint because $1/2(3t^2)'=3t$ but I'm not sure what to do with the imaginary number on the right side.